# Protect VBA Excel from saving by others

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to protect my Excel VBA from saving by others who are also using my macro. I tried using the below code but it is not working. I want to prevent others from saving the VBA Excel before closing as well as while using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for saving.

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "You cannot save this workbook"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work with the above code exactly?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and ask a question. Also note that *"it is not working"* is no useful error description. What does not work? What does your code actually do versus what did you expect it to do? • Note that the easist way to prevent saving is to open the workbook as read only (if this is an alternative for you).

Comment: Using this code, when closing the workbook it is saved. Change the content of a cell, click the close "X", press "Save" when prompted. The message "You cannot save this workbook" is shown, click OK, but the workbook is saved anyway. This can be confirmed by re-opening the workbook. I test this using "xlsb" format.

Comment: @RichardCrossley Tried it and I cannot reproduce what you say. And it works in Excel 2016 at least. • Pressed `X`, chose `Save` got the prompt and it did not save. Used xlsb as well.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, It might be explained by the fact I'm using Excel 2010 :-(  Good it works as expected in later versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Excel 2019 and I cannot reproduce your issue. The code works as expected. If I press <kbd>Save</kbd> I get the message box and it does not save. If I close the workbook, it asks me if I want to save, if I press <kbd>Save</kbd> I again get the message box and it does not save.

But you can try to add a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event with a `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` to make VBA believe the workbook was already saved. This prevents the message box when closing the workbook, that asks if you want to save or not.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "You cannot save this workbook"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not working excel 2016 still I am able to save the excel VBA

Comment: @DeepakL Do you get the message "You cannot save this workbook"?

Comment: @DeepakL Then your macros are not activated. Make sure they are enabled otherwise they cannot run.  See [Enable or disable macros in Office files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6) • Make also sure the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event is in `ThisWorkbook` and not in a module.

Comment: I marked it is solved, but I am not able to upvote since I do not have 15 reputation